# RegisteredListener.callEvent error on Java Bukkit Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm developing a Bukkit plugin, and one of the featues I'm working on involves a listener which detects when the player **right clicks** a bed, and sends a message to them and  writes data to a YML file (not the config). Before, it would do this whenever a bed was interacted with, but now when it's interacted with it brings up an error in the console.

Here's my listener:

```
public class listener
  implements Listener
{
  public static main plugin;

  public listener(main instance)
  {
    plugin = instance;
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(listener.plugin.getDataFolder(), "beds.yml");
    if(!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
        }
    YamlConfiguration yml = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    String dn = p.getDisplayName();
    dn = ChatColor.stripColor(dn);
    double x = p.getBedSpawnLocation().getX();
    double z = p.getBedSpawnLocation().getZ();
    double y = p.getBedSpawnLocation().getY();
    World w = p.getBedSpawnLocation().getWorld();
    String wn = w.getName();
    if ((event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
        if (event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.BED_BLOCK)
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Bed home set!");
            yml.set(dn + ".x", x);
            yml.set(dn + ".y", y);
            yml.set(dn + ".z", z);
            yml.set(dn + ".world", wn);
            try {
                yml.save(file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }

  }
}
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

http://pastebin.com/iYX27RnA (pastebin link because it takes up a lot of space)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please narrow down your problem into something more digestible? I'm trying to understand your issue here and I'm having troubles with that.

Comment: What is line 37 of your listener class?

Comment: @Jojodmo The 37th line is "    double x = p.getBedSpawnLocation().getX();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown when your code tries to call a method on an object that has a value of `null`. Your error also points out that the error is on line 37 of your `listener.java` class:

```
at me.Superior_Slime.bedhome.listener.onPlayerInteract(listener.java:37)
```

Which is the line:

```
double x = p.getBedSpawnLocation().getX();
```

The problem is one of two things:

1. `p` is null
2. The value returned from `p.getBedSpawnLocation()` is null

We know that it isn't #1, because there can't be a `PlayerInteractEvent` with no player, so, it has to be #2, the value returned from `p.getBedSpawnLocation()` is null.

The problem is that the Player from the `PlayerInteractEvent` does not have a bed spawn location, so, `p.getBedSpawnLocation()` returns null. Then, when you try to call another method on it, like `.getX()`, you get a `NullPointerException` because you tried to call a method on an object that was null.

To fix this, you should create an if statement that checks weather or not the player has a bed spawn location:

```
if(p.getBedSpawnLocation() != null){//the bed spawn location is not null
  //code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out I made another mistake in which I misplaced the second **if** statement.

Comment: Quick note, in normal practices, the player will never be null, but this is not a guarantee. Plugins may call the PlayerInteractEvent manually with a null player should they choose to do so. Other than that, great description of NPEs.